# TensorFlowFederated: Passing tensor to tff.federated_computation

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I have trialled TFF tutorial (MNIST) on my single machine and now I am trying to perform a multi-machine process using MNIST data.

Clearly, I cannot use `create_tf_dataset_for_client` so I have used GRPC to learn how to pass data from one machine to another.

My scenario is that Server will dispatch the initial model (with zeroes) to all the participating clients where the model will run on local data. Each client will dispatch the new weights to the server that will perform federated_mean.

I was thinking of using `tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process` where I could hopefully customise the `next` function (2nd argument) but I failed... I am not even sure if we use this approach to send the model and get the weights back from remote clients.

Then I thought I could use `tff.federated_mean` under `@tff.federated_computation` decorator. However, since weights are arrays and I have a list of them (as I have a number of clients), I am unable to understand how do I create a `tff.FederatedType` that points to that a list of lists. Any help from someone who has modelled federation on distributed dataset will be handy to understand.

Regards,
Dev.

Answer (score 3):

TFF computations are designed to be platform/runtime agnostic; a single computation can be executed by several different backends.

TFF's type system can be helpful here in reasoning about how data is expected to flow in you computation. See the [custom federated algorithms part 1 tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/custom_federated_algorithms_1) for an intro to how TFF thinks about types.

The result of `build_federated_averaging_process` expects an argument of datasets which are placed at clients; for a dataset of element type `T`, in TFF's usual notation this would be denoted `{T*}@C`. This signature particular is agnostic with respect to *how* the datasets arrive at the clients, or indeed how the clients themselves are represented.

Materializing the data and representing the clients is really the job of the *runtime*. TFF provides a few so-called [native](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/tree/master/tensorflow_federated/python/core/backends/native) options here.

For example, in the local Python runtime clients are represented by threads on your local machine. Datasets are simply eager `tf.data.Dataset` objects, and the threads pull data from the datasets during training.

In the remote Python runtime, clients are represented by (threads on) remote workers, so that a single remote worker could be running more than one client. In this case, as you note, data must be materialized on the remote worker in order to train.

There are several options for accomplishing this.

One, TFF will actually handle serialization and deserialization of eager datasets across this RPC connection for you, so you could use the *identical* pattern of specifying data as in the local runtime, and it should "just work". This pattern actually got significantly better in March of 2021, via the use of `tf.raw_ops.DatasetToGraphV2`.

Perhaps better mapping to the concepts of federated computation, however, is the use of some library functions to simply *instantiate the datasets on the workers*.

Suppose you have an iterative process `ip`, which accepts a `state` and `data` argument, where `data` is of type `{T*}@C`. Suppose further we have a TFF computation `get_dataset_for_client_id`, which accepts a string and returns a dataset of appropriate type (IE, its TFF type signature is `tf.str -> T*`).

Then we can compose these two computations into another:

```py
@tff.federated_computation(STATE_TYPE, tff.FederatedType(tf.string, tff.CLIENTS))
def new_next(state, client_ids):
  datasets_on_clients = tff.federated_map(get_dataset_for_client_id, client_ids)
  return ip.next(state, datasets_on_clients)
```

`new_next` now requires the controller to only specify the *ids* of clients on which to train, and delegates responsibility for pointing to a data store to whoever is representing the clients.

This pattern I think is likely what you want; TFF provides some helper s like the `dataset_computation` attribute on [`tff.simulation.ClientData`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/ClientData) and [`tff.simulation.compose_dataset_computation_with_iterative_process`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/compose_dataset_computation_with_iterative_process), which will more or less perform the wiring we did above for you.

Comment: Thanks Keith for your response.

Comment: I understand the new APIs you mentioned should be used to achieve my goals. However, I am kind of stuck on the "next" function of iterative process as to how will it point to a remote dataset (on a separate GPU)? 

More specifically, your function "get_dataset_for_client_id" I think will bring the dataset from the client to the server while we are trying to dispatch the model to the client GPU where data resides. 

Once I am past this, I can use the APIs you mentioned but still unable to get past the problem mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

let's do this step by step. Please let us know if the explanation below answers your question.

1. Let's start with an example of TF (non-federated, just local) code that takes a dataset and does something with it, say add numbers:

```
@tff.tf_computation(tff.SequenceType(tf.int32))
def process_data(ds):
  return ds.reduce(np.int32(0), lambda x, y: x + y)
```

This code takes a dataset of integer numbers at input, and returns a single integer with the sum at output.

You can confirm this by lookin at the type signature, like this:

```
str(process_data.type_signature)
```

You should see this:

```
(int32* -> int32)
```

So, `process_data` takes a set of integers, and returns an integer.

2. Now, using TFF's federated operators we can create a federated computation that does this on multiple clients, like this:

```
@tff.federated_computation(tff.FederatedType(tff.SequenceType(tf.int32), tff.CLIENTS))
def process_data_on_clients(federated_ds):
  return tff.federated_map(process_data, federated_ds)
```

If you look at the type signature of this new computation (just like above), you will see this:

```
({int32*}@CLIENTS -> {int32}@CLIENTS)
```

It means `process_data_on_clients` takes a federated set of integers (one set per client), and returns a federated integer (one integer with the sum on each client).

What happens in the above is that, the TF logic in `process_data` will be executed once on each client. This is how the `federated_map` operator works.

3. Now, `process_data_on_clients` is a little bit like the the iterative process you are working with. It wants you to provide a federated dataset as an argument.

Let's see how we can make one by following the same pattern as above.

Here's some TF code that creates a single dataset with integers, say you supply an integer `n` and want to create a dataset with numbers from 1 up to n, i..e, {1, 2, ..., n}:

```
@tff.tf_computation(tf.int32)
def make_data(n):
  return tf.data.Dataset.range(tf.cast(n, tf.int64)).map(lambda x: tf.cast(x + 1, tf.int32))
```

This is obviously a silly example, you could do something more along the lines of what you need (e.g., read data from a file specified by a name, etc.).

And here's what its type signature looks like:

```
(int32 -> int32*)
```

You can see the similarity to `process_data`.

And, just like with processing data, here's now we can make data on all clients by using the `federated_map` operator:

```
@tff.federated_computation(tff.FederatedType(tf.int32, tff.CLIENTS))
def make_data_on_clients(federated_n):
  return tff.federated_map(make_data, federated_n)
```

This is the type signature:

```
({int32}@CLIENTS -> {int32*}@CLIENTS)
```

Great, so `make_data_on_clients` takes a federated integer (that tells us how many data items to produce on each client), and returns a federated dataset, just like what `process_data_on_clients` wants.

You can check that the two work together as intended:

```
federated_n = [2, 3, 4]
federated_ds = make_data_on_clients(federated_n)
result = process_data_on_clients(federated_ds)
result
```

You should get the sums 1+2, 1+2+3, and 1+2+3+4 on the 3 clients involved in this computation (note there were 3 numbers in the federated integer above, so there are 3 clients here):

```
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=3>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=6>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=10>]
```

Note that all TF code you have seen so far, including both dataset creation and dataset reduce, were being executed on the clients (using `federated_map`).

4. Now, you can put the two together:

```
@tff.federated_computation(tff.FederatedType(tf.int32, tff.CLIENTS))
def make_and_process_data_on_clients(federated_n):
  federated_ds = make_data_on_clients(federated_n)
  return process_data_on_clients(federated_ds)
```

And now, you can invoke the make and process data combo in one shot:

```
make_and_process_data_on_clients(federated_n)
```

Again, all TF code here is executing on clients, just like in the above.

5. So where does this leave you?

Going back to Keith's explanation, the iterative process you got from TFF wants a federated dataset at input, just like `process_data_on_clients`.

The function `get_dataset_for_client_id` in Keith's example is like our `make_data` in that it is assumed to contain TensorFlow code that you want to run on each client to physically construct a dataset on that client.

In out silly example, dataset construction logic used `range`, but it can be anything. For example, you could load data on each client from the same local file `my_data`, or using a custom TF op, or by whatever other means. Just like in our example, you can pass parameters to that function to give you more centralized control (similarly to whatever did above with the federated integer).

The code snipper `new_next` in Keith's example is just like our `make_and_process_data_on_clients`, in that it combines two federated computations: one that makes federated data on clients (supplied by you, just as discussed here), and one that processes that data (from tff.learning, the iterative process).

Does this help?

If still unclear, I would recommend to try the examples I included above on your distributed setup, since you already have one. You could inject some TF print ops to that code to confirm that the TF code you wrote is executing on the client machines in your system.

Once you get that part, it's simple tweak to replace the silly data set construction logic in `make_data` with one that loads a dataset on each client from whatever local data source you are using.

EDITS:

Re: how to print, any TensorFlow code that appears in the body of a @tff.tf_computation is executed in eager mode, and you can use standard TensorFlow mechanisms such as tf.print to print from within TensorFlow.

tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print

On how to configure a multi-machine system with multiple worker nodes, see the Kubernetes tutorial. Note that the machine that drives the process connects to worker nodes, not the other way round.

https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/high_performance_simulation_with_kubernetes

Comment: Thanks @Krzys for your response. Based on your feedback, we are now trying to set up a simple scenario on 3 separate machines before trying out more complex things: 1 server (CPU) & 2 clients (GPUs).

The server hosts a grpc server that by running the suggested standard docker command on port 8080. This uses LocalExecutor. New channel requests are sent by the clients and  RemoteExecutor is launched. 

How can we print something using on either server or client that gets printed on the other machine? We just want to prove that queries can be sent back and forth.